# how to change more than one value in the same column? Sequelize

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sequelize.js, backend

I have a problem.

I have 1 table, where it stores a ranking of a clan

[image: Image ranking Clan]

and in my front-end I need to edit, but it is 1 form, with 3 inputs

[image: Frontend Inputs]

I send the rankings, and get them in my backend body, but I need to do an update, but I only have 1 column.
how to make?
I tried in different ways

[image: my last attempt]

when I edit, it stores the same value for the 3 columns.

Comment: can you show us the output of test before your loop?  i never tried to use a resultset the way you are to do an update, but i have plenty of examples of using the model and supplying the id and column that changed to the update of that model

Comment: @GregBelyea thanks for the answer, i tried to do it in different ways, for some reason it doesn't add one stop each, and i couldn't add one in each row. I tried to send an array of objects from the frontend, with the name and id, for me to compare the one on the backend, but it also didn't work.
the test output is as follows.

[![Outputs test][1]][1]
[![Database shows][2]][2]

[1]: https://i.imgur.com/Y1qGJiK.png
 [2]: https://i.imgur.com/WY8qm1Y.png